# how can I correct php/json syntax error?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I can retun this with json/php

```
exit('[{"name":"signup","state":"1","message":"this is a message"}]');
```

but not this:

```
$_SESSION["message"] = 'link: <a href="'.ROOT_URL.'/index.php?id='.$pid.'"> here </a>';

exit('[{"name":"signup","state":"1","message":"'.$_SESSION['message'].'"}]');
```

how can correct it?

Answer (score 2):

JSON uses double quotes to encapsulate strings, and you're simply concatenating in a string that contains unescaped double quotes which breaks the encoding.

To ensure that all of your data is encapsulated and encoded properly do something like:

```
$data = [
  'name' => 'signup',
  'state' => '1',
  'message' => $_SESSION['message']
];
echo json_encode($data);
exit();
```

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) handles escaping, encoding, conversions, and anything else necessary to produce properly-formatted JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this at easiest way , follow my steps.
**Dont make JSON manually.**.

Use this:

1. Make an array first.
2. Than use `json_encode` . You will get your data. correctly.